# Subtract Values within a hash array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to subtract two values that I have in a hash array in order to know the growth I have of the Discard Value.

My array is this:

```
array = 
{"SiteA": [
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16617331511, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:27 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16617216094, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:22 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16617202279, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:18 AM"},
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16616985649, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:12 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16616404836, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:07 AM"},  
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16616368250, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:03 AM"}
], 
"SiteB": [
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16617331511, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:27 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16617216094, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:22 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16617202279, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:18 AM"},
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16616985649, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:12 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16616404836, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:07 AM"},  
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16616368250, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:03 AM"}
]}
```

I want to subtract the values from 'discardmax' and get the following array.

```
[
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:115417, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:27 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:13815, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:22 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:216630, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:18 AM"},
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:580813, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:12 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:36586, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:07 AM"},
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:115417, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:27 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:13815, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:22 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:216630, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:18 AM"},
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:580813, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:12 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:36586, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:07 AM"}
]
```

In ruby I used this code but now I want to use javascript:

```
  keystotal = arrya.keys

  arr_sub = keystotal.map { |k|
    [k, groupedtotal[k].each_cons(2).map do |g,h|
    { devicetotal: g[:devicetotal], porttotal: g[:porttotal], device_int_stats_total: g[:device_int_stats_total], octetsrxsub: g[:octetsrxtotal]-h[:octetsrxtotal], octetstxsub: g[:octetstxtotal]-h[:octetstxtotal], time_unixsub: g[:time_unixtotal]-h[:time_unixtotal], time_unixtotal: g[:time_unixtotal], timeCapturedtotal: g[:timeCapturedtotal]}
  end
  ]
  }
  table_sub = arr_sub.map { |ts| ts[1] }
```

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Use `console.log(object, null, 2)` to get the data in an appropriate format. Also, it's not clear what value you want to subtract. If you know the algorithm, please explain it as text, and try and write it as code. We can help you if you have problems with the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array, subtracting `array[i+1].discardmax` from `array[i].discardmax`. Create a new object that merges this into a copy of `array[i]`.

```js
var array = 
{"SiteA": [
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16617331511, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:27 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16617216094, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:22 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16617202279, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:18 AM"},
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16616985649, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:12 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16616404836, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:07 AM"},  
 {device:"SiteA", discardmax:16616368250, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:03 AM"}
], 
"SiteB": [
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16617331511, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:27 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16617216094, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:22 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16617202279, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:18 AM"},
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16616985649, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:12 AM"}, 
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16616404836, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:07 AM"},  
 {device:"SiteB", discardmax:16616368250, timeCapturedmax:"February 18, 2018 at 09:03 AM"}
]};

var result = [];
for (var k in array) {
  var arr2 = array[k];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length - 1; i++) {
    result.push({ ...arr2[i],
      discardmax: arr2[i].discardmax - arr2[i + 1].discardmax
    });
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I updated the question. Please your support.

Comment: Just add another loop around it that processes the properties of the top-level object.